# syntax error near token ';'(homework)

Tags: linux, alias

I'm writing an alias that takes input for a file name and then after making sure the file is regular and readable copies the file using `cp -i` to the back up folder `$HOME/Backup`

I am very new to UNIX so I am experiencing some difficulties accomplishing this. Here is my code:

```
alias getname='read filename'

alias vfile='getname; if [ ! -f $filename ]; then echo "Irregular file"; (exit 1); elif [ ! -r $file ]; then echo "Not readable"; (exit 2); fi;'


alias backup='vfile; if [ vfile ]; then cp -i $filename $home/Backup; fi;'
```

I have tested the `vfile` alias and it works, the errors I am getting are:

`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'`

I started getting this error as soon as I included `vfile` as the first operation; if I don't run `vfile` before the if statement, it will use the filename from the last time it ran. I have to make sure that `vfile` did not produce an error before I can copy it.

Before I added `vfile` as the first command I got this error:

`cp: cannot create regular file '/Backup/*': No such file or directory`

but there is indeed a directory named Backup in my home folder so I don't know what's causing this either.

Comment: Is your instructor asking you to make these things aliases, or is that something you've come up with?  If you have flexibility, you might instead consider writing functions.  That'll enable you to more easily write multi-line expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Your alias `vfile` ends with a `;`, and then the alias `backup` starts off with `vfile;`. So that's two `;`s in succession without a statement in between, which is not allowed:

```
$ echo ; ;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Eliminate the `;` at the end of `vfile`.

Answer (score 2):

Use my alias from your last question instead of having the two aliases.

Since your vfile alias will throw an error code if wrong you can do this:

```
alias filebackup='vfile && cp -i "$filename" "$HOME/Backup/"'
```

The `&&` will tell it only to execute the `cp` command if `vfile` exits with `0`

**EDIT** *sorry I'm tired*

`$home` is not a valid environmental variable so unless you set it manually somewhere that explains why you got the no such file or directory error because it expanded to `''`.  Also always quote your variables.